# Boost-asio deadline_timer runtime error

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

So, I'm following a tutorial, trying to set up a basic timer...

```
void print(const boost::system::error_code &e)
{
  std::cout <<"hello world"<< std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io;
  boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
  timer.async_wait(print);
  io.run();
}
```

Builds fine, but at runtime;

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >'
  what():  thread: The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced
```

Win7, GCC, code::blocks

EDIT; Tried it on another machine with the same setup - same outcome.

EDIT AGAIN; Should I switch from boost 1_47 to whatever the latest is?

Comment: did you link to pthreads? Supply `-pthreads` for GCC

Comment: No dice. Is there a header I have to #include? Currently I just have asio.hpp and iostream.

Comment: Headers are fine as it is.

Comment: What do you recommend now?

Comment: I recommend you wait for someone to come around who recognizes your situation :| I think I'd have told you straight away if I knew the answer. Patience, Padawan (oh, and _read_)

Comment: Okay. (This is for SO's 15 char lower-bound on comments)

Comment: Tested with [GCC 4.7.3 and boost 1.55.0](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Mx9zYUgtgRZ4hwlo), worked fine.

Comment: Tested with Win7, VS2013 Express, boost 1.55, worked fine too. Which gcc and boost version are you using?

Comment: Boost ver 1_47, gcc ver 4.7.1 (funny coincidence)

Comment: where is the exception thrown? `async_wait()` or `io_service::run()`?

Comment: Strangely enough, it's thrown on the timer declaration. Passing no args to the constructor eliminates the error - albeit rendering the timer useless...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched boost 1.56, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me using MinGw 4.8 and boost 1.55. However, try changing the call to `timer.async_wait` to:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&print, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

Comment: Boost 1.47 ?!! I'd definitely recommend using boost 1.55. Note 1.56 was released today, so it may be a bit too new...

Comment: Okay, but do you think it's responsible for my problem?

Comment: In [boost 1.48.0 changelog](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_48_0.html), it is indicated that deadline_timer's implementation was changed. Anyway, with so many new versions, upgrading cannot do harm to you.